# MYSQL Join SUM with a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Sorry if this has been asked before but I just can't figure out a solution or find anything on it anywhere.

Basically what I need to do is display only amounts over 300 for a join that adds up a total amount from registrations with matching IDs

TABLES:
[image: table registration]
[image: table attendees]

In simpler table terms, TABLE A and TABLE B 
I need to get B.Amount total by joining WHERE A.ID and B.ID match and summing B.Amount where the B.ID is a repeat only. 
This is what I used to total up registrations paid by grouping payments by B.ID:

```
SELECT tblattendees.FirstName, tblattendees.LastName, 
SUM(tblregistration.RegistrationPaid) AS 'TotalPaid'
FROM tblattendees
JOIN tblregistration
ON tblregistration.RegistrationID = tblattendees.AttendeeID 
GROUP BY tblregistration.AttendeeID
```

This works fine till you want to limit the results to over 300

I have tried adding WHERE after the join and using AND with the ON but it seems to mess with the adding up probably due to my use of the GROUP BY to get a total of RegistrationsPaid.

Maybe some thing I'm not understanding in this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add at the end HAVING TotalPaid >300 .WHERE is pre aggregation filtering HAVING is post aggregation filtering

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not sure what aggregated filtering is but I'll look it up. I figured there was probably an issue with the calculation not occurring first.

Comment: WHERE is for rows HAVING is for groups

Comment: I see. Thanks for that, makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery and use condition in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT tblattendees.FirstName, tblattendees.LastName, 
  SUM(tblregistration.RegistrationPaid) AS `TotalPaid`
  FROM tblattendees
  JOIN tblregistration
    ON tblregistration.RegistrationID = tblattendees.AttendeeID 
  GROUP BY tblregistration.AttendeeID
) AS sub
WHERE sub.TotalPaid > 300
```

Or you can use `HAVING` as proposed in comment:

```
SELECT tblattendees.FirstName, tblattendees.LastName, 
SUM(tblregistration.RegistrationPaid) AS `TotalPaid`
FROM tblattendees
JOIN tblregistration
  ON tblregistration.RegistrationID = tblattendees.AttendeeID 
GROUP BY tblregistration.AttendeeID
HAVING SUM(tblregistration.RegistrationPaid) > 300
```

In `MySQL` you should use alias directly:

```
SELECT tblattendees.FirstName, tblattendees.LastName, 
SUM(tblregistration.RegistrationPaid) AS `TotalPaid`
FROM tblattendees
JOIN tblregistration
  ON tblregistration.RegistrationID = tblattendees.AttendeeID 
GROUP BY tblregistration.AttendeeID
HAVING `TotalPaid` > 300;
```

See also [`simplified order of execution`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx):

[image]

<sup>Image source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx</sup>

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response. I'll have to look more into having and I'll give both a try :)

Comment: I see you`re coming from sql server,mysql HAVING can see the alias

Comment: But in this instance there's no reason why you *would*

Comment: HAVING worked like a charm. 
Interesting sub query I was trying that just earlier and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, very educational response :)
That image is really helpful. Interesting that the select is last though, hard to think with that though at the same time kinda makes sense.

Comment: @RiCHiE It is. Think about it: `SELECT 10 AS col WHERE col > 5`

Comment: Well it makes sense the last thing is to SELECT the actual data.